# Return plain text from react Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to make a react component which would return me back plain transformed text. However, react enforces on returning at least one html wrapped around the content.

I thought of making adding a static utility function like this

```
@connect((state) => {
  return {
    state_val: state.state_val
  };
})

export default class Transform extends Component {
    ...
}

Transform.text = (text) => {
    // Need to access state here, but this.props.state_val
    // is not available till the Component is initialized
    return text.toUpperCase();
}
```

Not sure if this is a good pattern or not, but this works till I not try to access the state of course. Because state is available after the Component is initialized. Is there a way for me to access state somehow, may be manually initialize the Component.

Or, may be someway by which I can just do this

```
return (
    this.props.text.toUpperCase(); // It is not allowed though
);
```

Comment: Why do you need React for this? Can you not just make a normal function to which you pass whatever you want transformed?

Comment: I have to transform based on the value in the state. How would I access that value in a normal function? Take an example of the user selected currency

Comment: `transformCurrency(this.state.currency, userSelectedTextToTransform);` or something?

Comment: The problem is that the state is only available if I use the component like `<Transform />` Because only then it's initialized and available to use.

Comment: You'd need to use the function within some other component. http://jsfiddle.net/dL289fgw/

Comment: I'll give it a shot... Thanks